# Is there a way to hide all the origins in the 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way to hide the selected object's origin in the 3D view? By default all unselected object's origins do not show, but even after deselecting everything with <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> it still shows the active object's origin.
I know the *Only Render* checkbox will hide all the origins, but in this case it hides too much.

Comment: Additionally, to hide the Red Green Blue (RGB) axes (the "transform manipulator") press Ctrl + Space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Blender 2.8 and above:

You can hide the Origins for the active Objects and all Objects in the Overlay Menu.
[image: Viewport Overlays]

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can do is move the active object to a different layer or hide it.

1. Create a dummy object (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Hide it (<kbd>H</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Not a bad trick. But there is no way to just not show the origin on the selected object? Something like the opposite of *All Object Origins*

Comment: @David I don't think so. Why do you want to hide it? Maybe there is another solution..

Comment: It was rather unusual, I was comparing textured planes. I need to know which is selected, but don't want the origin blocking it. I know I could move the plane, but was curious.

Comment: Hm.. The selected object is still highlighted in wireframe view when only render is enabled. Perhaps you could switch back and forth between textured and wireframe views?