# Is it possible to hide the origin's display dot of the object(the black dot) from the viewport display ?

Tags: 3d-view

i was wondering this question. Here's the picture about that. It is that little black dot in the center. As far as i have learned it is just for displaying the center of mass. It often draws my attention and i need to hide it.  [image]

Comment: Try check the **Only Render** checkbox in the *Display* panel of the *properties shelf* (**N**).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Now possible in 2.8 and above: view [Is there a way to hide all the origins in the 3D view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15443)

In 2.7x and below it is not possible to hide only the center points. But if you need a clear view, you can activate **Only Render** in the Display Panel of the Properties Bar in the 3D View.

[image: Comparison of "Only Render" enabled vs disabled]

By the way the dot is not the center of mass, it is the center of transforms. (if you eg rotate the object, it will rotate around this point.) You can set the origin point to wherever you want with the weird shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.